# How to change windows decoration and scrollbar size in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

It is possible to have look&feel of Windows 7 in Windows 8 in Desktop mode?

Primary I would like to change windows decoration and e.g. scroll bar look&size and overall GUI controls look&feel, is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this Theme to get the Windows 7 Look:

[image]

http://mrgrim01.deviantart.com/art/Aero-8-Glow-364494879

You can get Aero Glass with this DLL:

http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/161788-aero-glass-for-win8-rc3/

Answer (score 0):

Use a program such as [WindowBlinds](http://www.stardock.com/products/windowblinds/) combined with a Windows 7 skin that replicates the exact look of the older OS' UI.

Comment: This software is not free. I should specify that I'm looking forsolution for free for personal use at least. But it really contains theme in trial edition that brings back the look&feel. Thanks!